# sed remove last 2 numerals

Tags: bash, scripts, grep, sed, awk

I have the following.

```
oid=.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.xxx (these 0.xxx represent any random numeral)
```

I want to do the following

```
echo $oid | sed (some commands to remove 0.xxx)
```

and store the resulting string

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5
```

in oid.

I don't mind this being done with Grep, awk or sed anything.
Everything before 0.xxx can change only thing static will be 0.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is a default form?

Comment: Yeah all will end with 0.xxx. I have to remove 0.xxxx. However everything before the 0 can change.

Comment: @SamFlynn In the original oid= , I see there's  10 dots. Or technically speaking - 10 fields separated by dots. Is that gonna always be the same amount ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With bash's [Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.xxx"
oid="${oid%.0.*}"
echo "$oid"
```

Output:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5
```

Answer (score 4):

As you said this is a general form, you want to remove the last 6 characters from your text(.0.xxx), so you can use this:

```
echo ".1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.xxx" |sed 's/.\{6\}$//'
```

Then if you want use with variables:

```
oid=.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.xxx
```

Then:

```
echo $oid | sed 's/.\{6\}$//'
```

output is:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5
```

#### Another solution

```
echo "${oid:0:${#oid}-6}"
```

#### Another solution using cut and '.' as delimeter

```
echo $oid | cut -d '.' -f -10
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`:

```
oid="$(echo -n .1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.0 | sed -r 's/\.0\.[0-9]+$//')"
```

`-r`: makes `sed` interpret `ERE` (Extended Regular Expressions) patterns

`sed` command breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `\.`: matches a `.` character
- `0`: matches a `0` character
- `\.`: matches a `.` character
- `[0-9]+`: matches 1 or more digits
- `$`: matches the end of the line
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the modifiers

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.xxx"
awk -F'.' '{for (i=2;i<=NF-2;i++) {printf "%s","."$i} }' <<< "$oid"
```

or all in one

```
awk -F'.' '{for (i=2;i<=NF-2;i++) {printf "%s","."$i} }' <<< ".1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.xxx"
```

*Output*

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5
```

*Short explanation*

`NF-2` – all elements without the last two elements

Comment: To have a new line without having to say `print ""` you can always say `printf "%s%s","."$i,(i<NF-2?OFS:ORS)`. This way, it will print a `ORS` (normally new line) after the last item.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -Po '.*(?=\.0\.\d+$)'
```

**Test :**

```
$ oid='.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.908'

$ oid="$(grep -Po '.*(?=\.0\.\d+$)' <<<"$oid")"

$ echo "$oid"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5
```

- `grep -P` will enable us to use PCRE
- `grep -o` will output only the matched portion
- `.*(?=\.0\.\d+$)` will match all characters prior to `.0`, followed by `.` and any number of digits at the end.